# Sturm–Liouville problem: approximating potential.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Let one-dimentional Sturm–Liouville problem:
$$
\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}+U(x)f(x)=\lambda f(x)
$$
with some appropriate boundary conditions, have a set of solutions $\{\lambda_i,\phi_i\}$.

Let further the sequence of functions $u^{(n)}(x)$ uniformly converge to $U(x)$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Is it true, that assuming the same boundary conditions the set of solutions of the approximate problem
$$
\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}+u^{(n)}(x)f(x)=\lambda f(x),
$$
$\{\lambda^{(n)}_i,\phi^{(n)}_i\}$ converges to $\{\lambda_i,\phi_i\}$?

Comment: If you are working on a finite interval $[a,b]$ with separated endpoint conditions, then you do get what you want.